# Rewriting SQL of counting offers made by user

Tags: sql, performance, join, count

I have two tables Cargo and Offer. I just want to list all cargos along with count of valid offers which has an offer made by particular user.
Table structure is as fallows:

**Cargo - Table**
CargoId
CargoTime
..

**Offer - Table**
OfferId
CargoId
UserId
OfferStatu
..

In this system users can make multiple offers for a cargo but latest offer will be count as valid  for particular user. So if OfferStatu is 1 then this refers to a previous offer of particular user.

I wrote SQL as follows assuming:

```
SELECT cargo.CargoId,cargo.CargoTime,COUNT(offer.OfferId) 
FROM cargo INNER join offer on offer.CargoId=cargo.CargoId
WHERE cargo.CargoId in
(
    select c.CargoId from cargo as c inner  join offer as o 
    on o.CargoId=c.CargoId
    WHERE o.UserId=12  
)
and offer.OfferStatu<>1
GROUP BY cargo.CargoId
```

But this query executed in approximately 1 seconds which is too much for me. I know that there is a more efficient way to write but I am struggling right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little difficult to tell from your question, but I assume that you are looking for a count of *all* offers associated to a cargo, even if they weren't made by the particular user you're searching for.  (for example, if a cargo had offers from users 10 and 12, then the count would be 2, even though we're only searching for user 12)

Try this out:

```
SELECT
  cargo.CargoId,
  cargo.CargoTime,
  COUNT(offer.OfferId) AS OfferCount
FROM
    cargo
  INNER JOIN
    offer
  ON
    offer.CargoId = cargo.CargoId
WHERE
  offer.OfferStatu <> 1
GROUP BY
  cargo.CargoId,
  cargo.CargoTime
HAVING
  SUM(CASE offer.UserId WHEN 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) <> 0;
```

([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e66c4/1))

As to whether this will be more efficient than what you currently have, that usually depends on your particular case, and you'll have to test to make sure.  One would expect this query to be more efficient since there's only one access of the cargo and offer tables, but it really depends.

Comment: Perfect ,  i really appreciate your effort and this is what exactly i am looking for. Your solution now takes only 0.031 seconds.